# How to bind and unbind mouse events on Marionette

Tags: events, backbone.js, bind, unbind, marionette

I have this event in my view:

```
    events:
        "click" : "clickContainer"
```

How can I unbind/bind (able and disable) temporary the click event in the same View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to remove the events map and use the manual version of what the events map sets up.

```
onShow: function() {
  this.enableClick();
},

enableClick: function() {
  $(".clickContainer").on("click", this.onClickContainer);
},

disableClick: function() {
  $(".clickContainer").off("click", this.onClickContainer);
},

onClickContainer: function() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have a property on the view. Something like this:

```
var View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.clickEnabled = true;
    },
    events: {
        'click': 'clickContainer'
    },
    clickContainer: function() {
        if ( this.clickEnabled ) {
           // do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

then you just change that property when you want to change the state.